# How to return object from an anonymous inner class in java

Tags: java, android, function, anonymous-inner-class

If I have the following function :

```
        public class Product {

    public String barCode;
    public String name;
    public Category category;
    public double price;
    public Store store;
    WebService ws = new WebService();

    public product getProduct(String barcode) {

        final Product p = new Product();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Product");
        query.getInBackground("XxfqN425pK", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("((((( name )))))", name);

                    String name1 = "p=" + object.getString("product_name");
                    p.name = name1;

                } else {
                    p.name = "erro" + e.getMessage();

                }
            }
        });
        return p;

    }

    public Product get() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

why `p.name` coming from the `getProduct()` call is always null despite the `Log` statement display a value for name

where to call the function:

class getProduct extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected Product doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Product p = new Product();
    return p.getProduct("");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Product result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.d("Product name >>>", result.name + "--");
}
```

}

Comment: Is the name variable for p being set anywhere?

Comment: It happens asynchronously.

Comment: Because you initialise p to a new Product(), don't do anything to it, then return it.

Comment: `getInBackground` suggests asynchronous call, are you sure the callback is invoked before you check the value? Also, what is the `name`?

Comment: I have updated the code , please check

Comment: Show us the client code.

Comment: Make `Product p` as global variable then inside your `get()` return p

Comment: @MarcinŁoś: I think he's using the getInBackground documented [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getInBackground(java.lang.String, com.parse.GetCallback)) , so it appears you're right.  This looks like a timing problem to me.

Comment: Suggestion: If you still haven't figured it out, add `p.name = "NOT YET";` just after setting `p` to `new Product()`, then see if that shows up in the output instead of `null`.  If so, then the problem is things happening in the wrong order, in different threads.  If it's still `null`, you can rule that out.

Comment: corrected link to [getInBackground javadoc](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getInBackground(java.lang.String,com.parse.GetCallback))